# Creating shapefile with features in GISPro?

Tags: shapefile, kml, kmz, ipad

We cannot figure out how to create a shapefile that contains the features seen within the app GISPro (by Garafa) on an iPad.

I have been able to export a shapefile, but there are no features attached to it.
I have been able to create a KML/KMZ, and the features are there but buried within a ton of HTML and all crammed together.

If it helps, the original data was created in GISKit (also by Garafa) but we upgraded when we couldn't get useful exports hoping that the shapefiles (which we need to end up with) would auto create the features.

Any ideas?

Comment: Would suggest contacting the app developers (a bug?) http://gis.garafa.com/GISPro_%26_GIS_Kit/GIS_Pro_&_GIS_Kit_for_iPhone_&_iPad_files/GISKit_Pro_Overview_11_08.pdf says pro will export shapefiles

Comment: It's been like talking to a rock getting "help" from them. Maybe if they had a phone number and not just an email.

Comment: If the question is still relevant, please describe more detailed your process of creating features and exporting them.